# Using sudo access with NET_SFTP phpseclib

Tags: php, ubuntu

Is it possible to use sudo access while using PHPseclib library?
I'm trying to edit a file which user doesn't have permission to without sudo.

Comment: You can, please have a look at http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#sudo